# Add New Calendar item default All Day Event

Tags: calendar

Is there any way to make "All Day Event" the default for adding a new calendar item without running a script. Our environment does not allow scripts to run so I cannot use the jquery.min.js to perform that, so I needed to know if there are any other methods to set this up?
Below is what I was trying to use and it didn't work so I'm assuming it was because our environment doesn't allow scripts to run. I followed the process on this link: 
 http://news.thrivefast.com/default-all-day-event-to-true/
I copied the jquery-2.1.1.min.js to our documents folder first then added the following script to "Edit HTML sSource" in content editor which I added to the list page for the calendar:

```
<script src="http://PATH/Documents/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"        
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){$('#ctl00_ctl34_g_269284a8_768b_44ec_b1e1_43bd1b219be7_ctl00_ctl05_ctl06_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_AllDayEventField').attr("checked","checked"); // checks All Day Event
//hide check-box
$('tr:has(span[title=All Day Event])').not('tr:has(tr)').hide();
});
</script>
```

Comment: I was able to get it working using a text file using the information [here](http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/categories/sharepoint2010/sharepoint2010customization.aspx?ID=ca8cd0bf-2839-4635-8727-9de6ddba4824)

Comment: Please do not post link-only answers. Instead include relevant parts from the link in your answer as well